# how to execute MongoImport command in yii?

Tags: php, mongodb, yii

Im using yiimongodbsuite extension to connect to mongodb, how to execute mongoimport command in php, here my code,

```
<?php

// connect

$m = new Mongo("mongodb://192.168.1.7:27017");

$db = $m->test;

$collection = $db->cartoons;

$db = 'mongoimport --db test --collection ' . $collection . ' --file test.csv --type csv'; 

    //Here after how to proceed to import the data??
?>
```

Comment: Your gonna want to exec that

Comment: Yes want to execute  from yii

Comment: No I mean exec: http://php.net/function.exec

Comment: I have used this code but not working,                exec('mongoimport --db test --collection ' . $collection . ' --file test.csv --type csv');

Comment: What is it coming back with? It will normally return an error if its not working

Comment: No, error is not showing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44051/discussion-between-manadh-and-sammaye)

Comment: Getting this error array(3) { ["errmsg"]=> string(45) "exception: SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier" ["code"]=> int(16722) ["ok"]=> float(0) }

Comment: why are you assigning the command to $db. instead use another variable and then exec($query)

Comment: Why don't you just read the CSV directly with [`fgetcsv()`](http://www.php.net/fgetcsv) or similar and insert directly via the MongoDB driver?  Calling `exec()` with `mongoimport` isn't saving you much effort, and you have less flexibility on how to handle the CSV import.

Comment: you need to add --host 192.168.1.7 to your mongoimport command.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, yiimongodbsuite  has nothing to do with executing shell commands, it only uses the mongodb php driver.

You are just overwriting you `$db` value with a string. It doesn't do anything.

You might as well replace all that code with :

```
<?php

$command = 'mongoimport 
    --db test 
    --collection cartoons 
    --file test.csv 
    --type csv 
    --host 192.168.1.7';
$result = exec($command);
```

Although your `php.ini` needs you to allow to use exec, which is usually not allowed on shared hosting. another thing you need to be aware of, is that your script might take some time to execute, depending on how big your csv is.

So you could improve that by adding:

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 300); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
```

Although that again requires your host to allow you to do `ini_set()` in the first place.

Curtsy to @asya-kamsky for pointing out the host